# Using LSSharedFileList

Tags: cocoa

I was looking at the LSSharedFileListCreate function in LSSharedFileListQuestion and it's defined as:

```
LSSharedFileListCreate(CFAllocatorRef inAllocator, CFStringRef inListType,CFTypeRef listOptions)
```

inAllocator and listOptions are always set as null. I was wondering if there were any other valid values for them besides null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LSSharedFileListCreate` follows the same conventions as other Core Foundation functions.

The `CFAllocatorRef` you provide can be `kCFAllocatorDefault`, `kCFAllocatorSystemDefault`, `kCFAllocatorMalloc`, `kCFAllocatorMallocZone`, `kCFAllocatorNull`, or `kCFAllocatorUseContext`.

The one you want to use in most cases is `kCFAllocatorDefault`, which is synonymous with `NULL`, as explained in the interface file.

The value you provide to `listOptions` depends entirely on which value you provide; some have associated values, and some do not.

For example, if you provided `kLSSharedFileListVolumesComputerVisible` in `inListType`, you'd provide a `CFBoolean` value indicating `TRUE` or `FALSE` in `listOptions`. If you provided the example `kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems`, you'd provide NULL, since there's no associated value.

Comment: So if I provide `kLSSharedFileListRecentDocumentItems` in `inListType` is there an associated value for `listOptions`? I want to be able to get the recent projects from a specified application, such as Xcode, not from all applications.

Comment: According to LSSharedFileList.h, no, there is no associated value. See my answer to your other question. I assumed there that your application is document-based; this would get you the recent files for your specific application.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I want to get recent files for an outside application, not necessarily my specific application and I was wondering if there was a way to do that.